# Creating as many environment variables as requested by an environment variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, environment-variables

So i want to create a variable number of environment variables, where `servnuber` is the number of environment variables i want and which is provided as an environment variable itself.

```
servnumber=os.environ['SERV_NUMBER']
vartest='host'
envtest='MY_HOST'
for x in range(1, servnumber):
    vartest+str(x)=os.environ[envtest+str(x)]
```

My desired result would be, if servnumber is 3, to create

```
host1=os.environ['MY_HOST1']
host2=os.environ['MY_HOST2']
host3=os.environ['MY_HOST3']
```

But I'm getting:

```
File "variableservers.py", line 49
    vartest+str(x)=os.environ[envtest+str(x)]
    ^ 
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables) TL;DR don't do that... Use a list instead...

Comment: You mean saving the variables in a list instead of host1, host2, etc?

Comment: Well I can't write a comment as simply YES

Comment: I should change all the code but it might work, let me give a try